# Why WebView does not open a site?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

**Conditions:** I want to create a dialog which include WebView to show a special site, specifically [this](https://www.notion.so/Blog-Post-20f83114dc15488eb5684c8c29821a4b) (`https://www.notion.so/Blog-Post-20f83114dc15488eb5684c8c29821a4b`).

**Code:** I have writen this code in Kotlin:

```
     MyButton.setOnClickListener{

        val myWebVeiw = WebView(this)

        myWebVeiw.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true)
        myWebVeiw.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)
        myWebVeiw.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET)
        myWebVeiw.settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
        myWebVeiw.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true)

        myWebVeiw.loadUrl("https://www.notion.so/Blog-Post-20f83114dc15488eb5684c8c29821a4b")
        myWebVeiw.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

        androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(myWebVeiw)
            .setPositiveButton(applicationContext.getString(R.string.close)){ _, _ -> /*nothing*/ }
            .show()
    }
```

And I have added this permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**Problem:** When I tap the button I can see a dialog, but it is empty and not deployed.

**Question:** How to open this site in the dialog?

Comment: Have you added internet permissions to your AndroidManifest file?

Comment: @NatigBabayev oh, yes.

Comment: I tried your code and it works for other websites. However, with your current url I got following error logs:
`[ERROR:context_group.cc(136)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: WebGL1 blacklisted`

Comment: @NatigBabayev Yeah, thank you. I know, that some sites are opening, but i need site from notion.so

Comment: enable javascript..and try this may help you

Comment: @RezaulKarim I have tried. Nope, it does not solve the problem :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have contacted with Notion.so.
They have written to me this:

[image]

So, guys, some sites could be unreachable in Webview. From now we will know it.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It saved tons of my time. I don't really understand "security reasons" here - sounds very absurd to me

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
    myWebVeiw.setWebViewClient(object:WebViewClient() {
    fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view:WebView, url:String):Boolean {
        return false
    }
   })
```

like

```
  MyButton.setOnClickListener{

    val myWebVeiw = WebView(this)

    myWebVeiw.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true)
    myWebVeiw.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)
    myWebVeiw.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET)
    myWebVeiw.settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
    myWebVeiw.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true)

    myWebVeiw.loadUrl("https://www.notion.so/Blog-Post-20f83114dc15488eb5684c8c29821a4b")
    myWebVeiw.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

    myWebVeiw.setWebViewClient(object:WebViewClient() {
    fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view:WebView, url:String):Boolean {
        return false
    }
   })

    androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setView(myWebVeiw)
        .setPositiveButton(applicationContext.getString(R.string.close)){ _, _ -> /*nothing*/ }
        .show()
}
```